How can I expose paragraph type third_party_settings and other properties on JSON:API?
Paragraph type third_party_settings and other properties are not exposed on JSON:API.
Example:
drupal.com/jsonapi/paragraphs_type/paragraphs_type
or
const paragraphsTypes = await drupal.getResourceCollection(
  'paragraphs_type--paragraphs_type',
);
let paragraphsTypesMapping = [];
for (var index in paragraphsTypes) {
  const paragraphsType = paragraphsTypes[index];
  // Missing!
  const my_prop = 
  paragraphsType.third_party_settings.my_custom_module.extra_property;
};

Shows:
{
  "type": "paragraphs_type--paragraphs_type",
  "id": "38057145-61fd-451d-ad3f-dd0fdb300cd3",
  "links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://drupal.com/jsonapi/paragraphs_type/paragraphs_type/38057145-61fd-451d-ad3f-dd0fdb300cd3"
    }
  },
  "attributes": {
    "label": "My paragraph type",
  }
}

Should be:
{
  "type": "paragraphs_type--paragraphs_type",
  "id": "38057145-61fd-451d-ad3f-dd0fdb300cd3",
  "links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://drupal.com/jsonapi/paragraphs_type/paragraphs_type/38057145-61fd-451d-ad3f-dd0fdb300cd3"
    }
  },
  "attributes": {
    "langcode": "en",
    "status": true,
    "dependencies": {
      "module": [
        "my_custom_module"
      ]
    },
    "third_party_settings": {
      "my_custom_module": {
        "extra_property": "Some text"
      }
    },
    "drupal_internal__id": "my_paragraph_type",
    "label": "My paragraph type",
    "icon_uuid": null,
    "icon_default": null,
    "description": "",
    "behavior_plugins": []
  }
},

But for node type, they are here.
I can manually do entity type alter config_export and it shows in raw JSON response in attributes but only for the super administrator???
How can I get the extra properties exposed in Drupal 10 for paragraph entity types? (Not paragraph items themselves)

Drupal core's JSON:API will expose everything that the current user has access to.
By design, Drupal's JSON:API has no special permissions; the permissions are the same as what is at Admin -> People -> Permissions.
If you need to expose additional information via JSON:API, you should grant the appropriate permission to the desired user role.
In the specific case of third-party settings for the Paragraphs module, you should grant the role the administer paragraph types permission.
You'll also need to make sure that the user in question is authenticated to Drupal.

Do you know which permission I should change to get access?

Hey @patrick-kenny - it turns out that the permission required was administer paragraphs types.  If you add this to your answer, I am happy to accept it since it pointed me in the correct direction.
I also found out that I had to create an OAuth token for NextJS to authenticate with Drupal to use the correct scope/Drupal user role in it's JSON:API call. (@see also https://next-drupal.org/learn/graphql/configure-authentication

https://next-drupal.org/learn/preview-mode/create-oauth-client
https://github.com/chapter-three/next-drupal/issues/15)


@JoshuaGraham Thanks for following up.  I've updated my answer.

Great. Accepted. Thanks for your help!
